# Корректное отображение даты из Unix UTC

Tags: java, android, дата, openweathermap

От сервера приходит дата в формате "Time of data calculation, unix, UTC" и значение равно, например 1473777482.

В приложении делаю обработку для более читабильного формата и присваиваю значение в поле TextView:

```
Date date = new Date(resp.getDt() * 1000)
mDateTextView.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("EE, dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm").format(date));
```

И вроде все ничего, но только отображается 14 сентября и время 2 часа (ночи). 
Каким образом можно привести с актуальному текущему времени по Мск.?

В теории можно просто отнять от текущего времени константу, которая равна разнице, но на мой взгляд это не очень корректно, да и скорее всего существует какой то способ, но я его не обнаружил.

Comment: попробуйте проверить настройки часовых поясов на компьютере

Comment: @Ksenia вы правы частично - в итоге на тестовом девайсе было выставлено некорректное время и дата. Но по хорошему не стоит зависеть от времени пользователя, а выдавать время то что вернул сервер и немного его изменить

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Просто установите нужную зону так:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EE, dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm")
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Comment: Вы оказались правы. Я так же не указал какое время возвращать - нужно то не серверное UTC, а местное, относительно UTC. С Вашей настройкой таймзоны отображал три часа дня, но в моем случае надо текущее время. По сему заменил метод getTimeZone("UTC") на getDefault().