# Как правильно перевести время из unix в человеческий вид?

Tags: java, android, unixtimestamp

Есть значение:

```
int innerDate = 1478086643;
```

Пытаюсь перевести следующим кодом:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm a");
        String date = sdf.format(innerDate);
```

Но в ответ получаю:

> Дата: January 18, 1970 at 5:34 AM,

хотя на сайте показывает:

> GMT: Wed, 02 Nov 2016 11:37:23 GMT

Подскажите, что я не так делаю или не правильно понимаю?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UnixTime в секундах, а вам нужны милисекунды для работы с классами Date и Calendar - просто нужно умножить на 1000

**UPD**

```
long timeInMillis = timeInSeconds * 1000
```

Comment: так же советую взять дефолтную таймзону  или любую другую вам подходящую format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); Я такой же вопрос задавал недавно - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/565912/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-unix-utc

Comment: изменил на `String date = sdf.format(innerDate * 1000);` , но ничего не изменилось..

Comment: @Denis422 `long` вместо  `int`

Comment: @georgehardcore благодарю, помогло.